# Error: Journal commit I/O error

Tags: linux

I am getting the error message 'journal commit I/O error'. What does this mean?

```
journal commit I/O error
EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_put_super: Couldn't clean up the journal
EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
EXT4-fs (sdc1): warning: checktime reached, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
EDD information not available.
session_init(service_process,82169): OK. kdev=8:3, bs=4096.
register_make_request(service_process,82169): OK. kdev=8:3, mq=0.
session_init(service_process,82169): OK. kdev=fd:1, bs=4096.
register_make_request(service_process,82169): OK. kdev=fd:1, mq=0.
```

When I do lsblk, I can't find /dev/sdb. Does this mean something has happened and /dev/sdb has now failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/O is a common shorthand for *input/output*. The filesystem driver found uncommitted (=incomplete) write operations in the filesystem journal, tried to complete (commit) them by writing the appropriate data to its final location on disk, and found that it couldn't do that because the disk was reporting errors.

As a result, the filesystem driver switched the `/dev/sdb1` filesystem to read-only mode to minimize the chances of further loss of data.

If the disk is no longer visible to `lsblk`, that might mean the error that stopped the filesystem journal commit operation also triggered the disk's internal diagnostics, with the result that the disk found itself seriously faulty and possibly shut itself down.

I'm sorry, but based on all you've told so far, it looks like your `/dev/sdb` disk might be dying or even already dead.

I hope you have up-to-date backups.

You probably should comment that disk out of `/etc/fstab` now to prevent problems at the next boot, assuming it's not your Linux system disk.

If the disk appears to be working again after a power off/on cycle, you should try `smartctl -x /dev/sdb`, and see what it has to report. Then you might want to use `ddrescue` to make an image of whatever parts of the disk are still readable before doing anything else.